# Basic Auth with Jenkins http-request-plugin

Tags: groovy, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to make a simple POST-request with the "Http Request Plugin". My problem is with getting the credentials to work. I have set a global credential,  `user:pass`.

But trying this in my code

```
withCredentials([usernameColonPassword(credentialsId: 'akamai', variable: 'akamai')]) {

    def response = httpRequest url: requestUrl, contentType: requestContentType, httpMode: requestHttpMode, requestBody: requestContent, authentication: akamai
    echo "Status: ${response.status}\nContent: ${response.content}"
}
```

results in

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication 'user:pass' doesn't exist anymore
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

HTTP Request Plugin v1.8.18 [now supports credentials in the Credentials Plugin](https://github.com/jenkinsci/http-request-plugin/releases/tag/http_request-1.8.18) (the HTTP Request Plugin v1.8.18 [now depends on v2.1.3 of the Credentials Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/HTTP+Request+Plugin)).

To perform an HTTP request using a Jenkins credential you can use the following code:

```
def response = httpRequest authentication: 'credentialsID', url: "http://www.example.com"
```

where `credentialsID` is the ID of the credentials in Jenkins:

[image]

The basic credentials under Configure System > HTTP Request now states that the Basic/Digest Authentication is deprecated and to use Jenkins credentials instead:

[image]

Comment: I did the same as you have mentioned in the answer but I am getting the error-java.lang.IllegalStateException: Authentication 'CredentialsID' doesn't exist anymore

Comment: Do you have a credential stored in Jenkins with the ID "CredentialsID"? If you view the Credentials in Jenkins it will display a table containing (amongst other things) the name and ID for each stored credential. It's the ID field you want to use

Comment: Yes I have created a Credential in Jenkins as you have mentioned in the answer and then I am using the ID of that Credetial. I have mentioned the details in question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48166066/http-request-using-jenkins-pipeline-job

Comment: Jenkins doesn't offer the ability to create basic auth credentials.  What type of credentials did you create to address that DEPRECATED note?

Comment: The credentials I used in the answer above are global scope credentials of the type "Username with password"

Comment: I did not have permission to create the new Jenkins credential. So, I used the Basic/Digest Authentication and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: what if you dont have a username and password? just a single token you would use like `curl -v -X POST https://MYTOKENSTRING@zzzz.com/api/method -d "param1=slflsf&param2=sdfsfsdf"`

Comment: It only works with the _username and password_ version, not with _username and  private key_

Comment: If you still need to pass "cleartext" credentials for Basic auth (e.g. you store them in Vault, not in Jenkins Credentials), you can craft the Authorization header like it's done in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-39744  Also note that `customHeaders` parameter now accepts `maskValue` to hide the base64 of username:password, see https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/ for more on this.

Answer (score 4):

The Credentials for the `Http Request Plugin` are not managed by the Credentials Plugin but rather under Configure System -> HTTP Request like shown in the picture.

[image]

Comment: This is deprecated now.