# HTTP Request using Jenkins Pipeline Job

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have been trying to do HTTP request in Jenkins Pipeline Job using **HTTPRequest plugin**

```
script{def response = httpRequest authentication: 'CredentialsID',  url: "https://host/api/project-summary/kj/?kj=123"}
```

I have created Credentials with the ID 'CredentialID' in Jenkins.

I am getting the following error when I build the job-
[image]

I have already referred to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41571090/basic-auth-with-jenkins-http-request-plugin) question on StackOverflow but it didn't help.

Could someone point out the mistake in this or is there some other approach that I can use to make HTTP Request from Jenkins Pipeline Job?

UPDATE: I have also created the Credentials with the ID - 'CredentialsID' in jenkins as shown below:
[image]

Comment: Is the last screenshot wrong? The ID shows "CSDLCredentialsID" but the ID you're using is "CredentialsID"

Comment: I have edited the screenshot. Actually I have multiple credentials in Jenkins and I took the wrong snapshot.

Comment: It's not due to the lowercase 'd' is it? "CredentialsId" rather than "CredentialsID"?

Comment: No, it's not due to that. I checked it and still getting the same error.

Comment: What are the versions of the HTTP Request Plugin and Credentials Plugin are you using?

Comment: Instead of setting credentials as shown in snapshot, I set the credentials under Manage Jenkins -> configure system and it started working.