# Check java coding styles using jenkins plugin

Tags: java, jenkins, plugins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Does anyone know a jenkins plugin for Java that analyses the coding styles and **fails the build** (not only provide a report) in case there are styles violations?

Comment: You should use maven checkstyle plugins in your pom as part of your build.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Findbugs` and `Checkstyle` for the same.

https://plugins.jenkins.io/checkstyle

https://plugins.jenkins.io/findbugs

Jacoco is used to unit test coverage and not really for static analysis.

Comment: Both these plugins have reached EOL and are deprecated now.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to use a plugin of your build tool(like jacoco plugin in your pom for maven build).

And then configure your jenkins pipline to fail if quality is not satisfying

Comment: And how exactly I can configure jenkins to do so?

Comment: refer to the answers of this question for more details https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40504535/how-to-react-on-sonarqube-quality-gate-within-jenkins-pipeline